# FreeMarker with DOM Change the inner html with freemarker functions

Tags: freemarker

I want to set the `innerHTML` for some tag as

```
${(widget.description!)?replace("href=", "target='_blank' href=")?replace("font-size", "notUsedValue")?replace("font-family", "notUsedValue")}
```

How I do something like that in javascript not in HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but i'm not sure about the performance and which is best

the replace function in freemarker as the same as in javascript then we can use the javascript replace function directly

```
 widget.description.replace("href=", "target='_blank' href=").replace("font-size", "notUsedValue").replace("font-family", "notUsedValue")}
```